# What are some references on intertextuality?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-culture

Intertextuality is [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertextuality).  It is a way to enrich a text by using reference to another text.

What would be a good reference on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

[Gérard Genette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9rard_Genette), [Paratexts : Thresholds of Interpretation](https://books.google.it/books?id=AmWhQzemk2EC&printsec=frontcover) (1997 - original French ed.*Seuils*, 1987).

See also : [Palimpsests : Literature in the Second Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palimpsests:_Literature_in_the_Second_Degree) (1997 - original French ed.1982).

Answer (score 0):

**Intertextuality**

> There are always other words in a word, other texts in a text. The concept of intertex-
>    tuality requires, therefore, that we understand texts not as self-contained systems but as
>    differential and historical, as traces and tracings of otherness, since they are shaped by the
>    repetition and transformation of other textual structures. Rejecting the New Critical 
>    principle of textual autonomy, the theory of intertextuality insists that a text cannot exist as
>    a self-sufficient whole, and so, that it does not function as a closed system. (María Jesús Martínez Alfaro, 'Intertextuality : Origins and Development of the Concept', Atlantis, Vol. 18, No. 1/2 (Junio - Diciembre 1996), pp. 268-285 : 268.)

This agrees with your reference; I include it to get a concise statement of the concept on screen.

**References**

There's a wealth to choose from :

Clayton, Jay and Eric Rothstein, eds. 1991. Influence and Intertextuality in Literary History. Madison: University of Wisconsin.

Culler, Jonathan 1976. Presupposition and Intertextuality. Modern Language Notes 91: 1380-396.

Foucault, Michel 1972 (1971). The Discourse on Language. The Archeology of Knowledge and the Discourse on Language. Trans. A. M. Sheridan Smith. New York: Harper & Row. 215-37.

Friedman, Susan Stanford 1991.'Weavings: Intertextuality and the (Re)Birth of the Author', Influence and Intertextuality in Literary History . Eds. Jay Clayton and Eric Rothstein. 146-80.

Johnson, Barbara 1987. 'Les Fleurs du Malarme: Some Reflections on Intertextuality', A World of Difference. Baltimore: Johns Hoppkins U.P, 116-133.

Plett, Heinrich F. 1991. Intertextualities. Intertextuality. Ed. Heinrich F. Plett. Berlin: De Gruyter. 3-29.

Worton, Michael and Judith Still, eds. 1990. Intertextuality: Theories and Practices. Manchester: Manchester University Press.